# While o i am trying to start i am getting the below error

Tags: mongodb, windows-7

While o i am trying to start i am getting the below error

> @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed
>
> C:\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongodb
>   'mongodb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo start
>   MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
>   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/start?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>   2019-03-06T15:44:04.853+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 1
>   27.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to
>   127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target m
>   achine actively refused it. :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

Answer (score 0):

Your using `mongodb` as command to start MongoDB but it should be `mongod`

To start [MongoDB Server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/), run mongod.exe. Using below command,

```
mongod --dbpath="<DATABASE DIRECTORY>"
```

Then you can connect with MongoDB, Using command `mongo`

*Default path MongoDB on Windows at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe`*